# How to place content in a footer next to eachother?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a footer kind of like this one [here](https://codepen.io/scanfcode/pen/MEZPNd)

Right now the issue I'm having is getting the content to sit beside eachother instead of stacked on top of eachother.

I've tried using display:flex but that moves everything, including text I want to stay in place, and that isn't the result I'm aiming for, so I'm not sure what to try next.

```css
.footer {
    background-color: #EB5931;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}


.pleft {
    width: 20%;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.74);
}
```

```html
  <div class="footer">

                    <h3 class="footerleft">THE DESIGN PROCESS</h3>
                    <p class="pleft">The design process includes many different parts, each used in their own way. 
                    </p>

                    <ul class="footernav">

                        <li>
                            HOME
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            ABOUT
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            DESIGNS
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            HELP
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                    <h3 class="contactus">CONTACT US</h3>
                    <ul class="contactinfo">
                        <li>
                            info@designer.com
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                123-456-7890
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                101-101-1010
                        </li>
                    </ul>


                    <hr>


                </div>
```

If anyone can help me figure this out, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you copy the code?

Comment: you need to wrap the heading and ul in a div, like Xenio did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used `display:flex`

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #EB5931;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.pleft {
  /* width: 20%; */
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.74);
}

.footer div {

width: 33.333%}
```

```html
<div class="footer">

  <div>
    <h3 class="footerleft">THE DESIGN PROCESS</h3>
    <p class="pleft">The design process includes many different parts, each used in their own way.
    </p>
  </div>


  <div>
    <ul class="footernav">

      <li>
        HOME
      </li>
      <li>
        ABOUT
      </li>
      <li>
        DESIGNS
      </li>
      <li>
        HELP
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3 class="contactus">CONTACT US</h3>
    <ul class="contactinfo">
      <li>
        info@designer.com
      </li>
      <li>
        123-456-7890
      </li>
      <li>
        101-101-1010
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>




  <hr>


</div>
```